# mysql server in ubuntu 13.04 not showing databases

Tags: server, mysql, lamp

i have installed `Xampp(LAMPP)` in Ubuntu 13.04 . i have secured the `xampp` `phpmyadmin` `Mysql` `FTP`. status showing ACTIVATED.now, i have installed mysql server.in terminal  write `mysql -u root -p` and then `password` and i connect with my mysql commandline. now `SHOW DATABASES;` i can only see  `information_chema`,`performance_schema` and `test` `mysql` and also showing db(abc) the created databases from the terminal command line. i can drop this 'abc' database from terminal but `abc` is not showing in phpmyadmin.and databse created in phpmyadmin not showing in terminal with `show databses;`.
 also could not drop databases from phpmyadmin `drop database statements are disabled` allowing me to create only.

thnks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is another mysql-server running in your computer. So when you log in to mysql using terminal, you are loggin into that one (Not the XAMPP one). 
To connect to mysql server in XAMPP you have to run `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root`

Comment: yeah it works. thnkx

Comment: Its working for me too. Thanks. can we sync these 2 server? (In my project, DB update takes mysql -u root server instead of /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root. So i always get unknown db error).